# Remote connection between Intelij and Tomcat running on unix machine

Tags: java, unix, web

Am getting into java web development and currently web server (tomcat) is running on the same laptop I use for coding. Now, I want to install FreeBSD on other computer, then install stuff like tomcat, some db server to learn more about unix and have a more real world environment. Idea is to have my laptop for coding (it uses win7 and InteliJ as IDE) and this other computer (freeBSD on it) for server side stuff. So my question is, how do I make this happen? Is there a way to connect intelij to that computer and have intelij acces its file system where my web related stuf would be stored. That sounds like a good way to do it. Give me some advice and pointers, Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you want.
IntelliJ will allow you to remote debug an application in the tomcat server.  However to have IntelliJ reload the application to tomcat requires the ultimate edition of IntelliJ.

That said you can write scripts or use Maven (Ant or Gradle) from within IntelliJ to deploy your application to Tomcat, its more clunky than the remote deploy option with ultimate.